# How long does it take for a character to get transfered to town after you disconnect while in an instance?

Tags: path-of-exile

When you disconnect in an instance your character gets transfered to town. How long does it takes for that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be sent back to town immediately.  Just like leaving any instance, that specific instance will remain open until it times out.